# rbenv install --list does not list version 2.1.2

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, osx-mavericks, rbenv

I installed `rbenv` via Homebrew on an OS X 10.9.3 MacBook Pro:

```
brew update
brew upgrade rbenv ruby-build
```

According to `rbenv install --list` on my laptop `Ruby 2.1.0-dev` is the latest.

Comment: see if you have it directly on ruby-build doing `ruby-build --definitions`

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu I do see 2.1.2 with `ruby-build --definitions`

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Both rbenv and ruby-build are generally installed from Github by cloning; That's how [the authors recommend we install it](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv).

```
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
```

If you didn't do it that way I'd recommend that method. Then, you can simply do:

```
cd ~/.rbenv
git pull
cd plugins/ruby-build
git pull
```

If you have several plugins use:

```
cd plugins
for i in *
do
  cd $i
  git pull
  cd -
done
```

I update every couple weeks just to pull in the latest fixes/changes.

Comment: I will give this a try. I just love how simple homebrew is. :D (When there are no issues)

Comment: I had the same problem. brew upgrade ruby-build did not work. Uninstalled it (/usr/local/Cellar/ruby-build/20140225) and reinstalled it and it made no difference.

I uninstalled ruby-build from brew and installed ruby-build plugin. Now I see ruby 2.1.2 available via 'rbenv install -l'

Comment: just to point out: these instructions also work with rbenv installed to a non-standard/non-homebrew location. Just change the `~/.rbenv` for your local install path (for example my machine, using boxen, puts rbenv in `/opt/boxen/rbenv`).

Comment: @levy brew is easy.  If you type `brew info ruby-build` then the keg info tells you to Pull.

Answer (score 59):

I faced the same issue. I got the latest by running the following command:

```
brew upgrade --HEAD ruby-build
```

Comment: I did `brew update`and then the upgrade shown here and it worked for me.

Comment: Had this problem trying to upgrade to 2.2.2 using rbenv and it wouldn't show up on the list until I did the upgrade shown here. Regular `brew upgrade` didn't work.

Comment: Originally just did a `brew install ruby` before realizing that this had no connection to the version of Ruby provided with most Apple computers.  So then ran `brew uninstall ruby` followed by `brew upgrade --HEAD ruby` and things worked just fine for me!

Comment: This worked for me: `brew update && brew upgrade ruby-build`

Comment: This worked for me HOWEVER, it complained that `--HEAD` was an invalid option. I believe this has been changed to `--fetch-HEAD`. So this worked for me: `brew upgrade --fetch-HEAD ruby-build`. After running that, I saw the version I was after (the latest).

Answer (score 17):

I had this issue on OS X 10.8.5 (so don't think OS related). I had tried updating rbenv & ruby-build via brew. 2.1.0-dev was still latest build available.

I had to force uninstall and re-install ruby-build via brew to fix the issue.

```
brew uninstall ruby-build --force
brew install ruby-build
```

Comment: I installed rbenv and ruby-build with brew, and this worked to update the list of rubies in rbenv install -l include version 2.1.4

Comment: Needed this solution to update my version list for an rbenv installed under homebrew, on OSX Sierra 10.12.1.  All other above solutions did not work.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue. Even after running

```
brew upgrade rbenv ruby-build
```

I still didn't get ruby-2.1.2 on the available list.
Following [how to update list of available ruby versions on linux](http://makandracards.com/makandra/25477-rbenv-how-to-update-list-of-available-ruby-versions-on-linux), I updated ruby-build through the following commands

```
cd ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
git pull
```

(I'm using OS X 10.9.4 MacBook Air)

Comment: This is the most-correct answer, as it doesn't involve anything radical.  The 'git pull' command can most-normally be found by running `brew info ruby-build`.  The command is printed with the keg info.

Answer (score 8):

This happened to me today. "rbenv install -l' displays outdated list while "ruby-build --definitions" returns the correct list. The problem is fixed by executing following command:

```
rm -Rf ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
```

It seems there is an outdated version of ruby-build under ~/.rbenv/plugins. Not sure when it got generated.

Comment: I notice duplication in my ruby-build --defintions. Running your command removed the duplication, thanks.

Comment: I couldn't find 2.1.4, this fixed it for me

Answer (score 7):

[This link](http://ryaneschinger.com/blog/updating-ruby-build/)
gives a good explanation of the two available options.

If you installed rbenv from the git repository:

`$ cd ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
$ git pull`

If you used Homebrew on OSX to install rbenv:

`$ brew update
$ brew upgrade ruby-build`

(Also running `brew doctor` might give you the exact solution.)

And if you have permission denied errors, this is my addition:

`$ sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local; brew update
$ sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local; brew upgrade ruby-build`

Then you'll be able to install the recent versions.

`$ rbenv install --list
$ rbenv install 2.1.2`

Answer (score 5):

The selected answer will work fine, but the issue may have simply been caused by homebrew not having an up-to-date formula for ruby-build at the time.  As of this posting, the appropriate ruby-build formula has been put into the latest version of homebrew.  So running:

`$ brew update`

should get you version needed to get the latest ruby.  Then, running `rbenv install --list` again should list 2.1.2 (and others).

So if anyone sees this later on, hopefully you can avoid having to maintain the individual repositories if you'd rather use homebrew for package management.

Answer (score 0):

I've just updated ruby-build and ruby-install to latest versions and both have the latest ruby 2.1.2

Probably rbenv doing something nasty.

Comment: rbenv isn't doing anything nasty. The OP is not maintaining the code.

Comment: if the OP updated homebew, rbenv and ruby-build and ruby 2.1.2 does not appear on the list there is something wrong for sure. And I'm saying it should be rbenv because ruby-build has the 2.1.2 version already. Probably rbenv does some sort of caching. Probably opening a new terminal window will solve the issue.

Comment: Well I have rebooted and opened new terminals windows, and still do not see 2.1.2. This is so weird.

Comment: What is also odd is that I checked on my iMac running OSX 10.8.5 and 2.1.2 is being listed in rbenv installed via brew.

Comment: I have rbenv installed (with brew) on 3 machines - all MacOS 10.9.3. On 2 machines, 2.1.2 is listed in the rbenv install --list. On the other, it is not.  ruby-build 20140524 and rbenv 0.4.0.  On the problem machine, ruby-build --definitions shows 2.1.2 as available.

Comment: The problem was multiple versions of ruby-build.  https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/569  I am not sure how or when the duplicate ruby-build version was installed.

Answer (score 0):

Following all the above, on OSX 10.11 it still wouldn't list the latest versions. What I did below worked for me- I removed the dir, re-installed from brew then I had to link in brew like this:

```
$ brew uninstall ruby-build --force
$ rm -Rf ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
```

and then

```
$ brew install ruby-build
$ brew link --overwrite ruby-build
```

and then I saw the most recent versions to build.

Answer (score 0):

> cd /home/[user]/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build && git pull && cd -

Don't forget to replace [user] with your user